# Drupal 7 Feeds importer handle file types additional fields

Tags: media, feeds

I have feeds importer which imports images. It works. The image field in the content type related to file type "**Image**". 
Recently we decided to add few additional fields (copyrights, caption) to file type "**Image**". 
I'm trying to find a way how to import the data to additional field of file types. 
1) I tried to check "**/mappers/link.inc**: file, it provides an opportunity separately import "URL" and "Title" for the link field, but link field is not file type. Anyway it was a good start.
2) Then I checked "**/mappers/file.inc**", but this file doesn't handle additional fields.

I can create a custom mapper for this case, but I'm not so familiar with Feeds API.

Does anybody already tried to handle additional fields for file types?
or Does anybody know any module which does it?